# Not able to create Azure Container Instance in the portal with private image

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry, azure-container-instances

I'm trying to create an Azure Container Instance in the portal with a private image. The validation seems to pass but I can't click OK. The button is disabled.

The private registry is an Azure Container Registry in the same subscription.

[image: Screenshot from Azure Portal]

Comment: did you try another browser\another pc etc

Comment: Are you still seeing this? Which browser?

Comment: @SeanMcKenna-MSFT Thanks, it worked now. Not sure what was causing the problem. I tried in several browsers before.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was resolved on your own after waiting between attempts. For future reference if you need to deploy a private image from the portal you need to include the hostname of the image like "myprivateregistry/nginx:latest".

We've also improved some error handling so deployment failures should also be easier to troubleshoot.